# How to add models in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some kind of problem when adding models to my Ruby on Rails project.
I have a cute cople of controller and model, but the controller cannot access the model because the symbol seems to be... undefined.

So it seems I don't understand AT ALL how Rails chooses which classes to load and which not to load.

Here's my model file (and YES, I know, I should have a file for each model. And I did. But I've been trying everything to make it work, and currently I just have one) :

```
class Feed
  include Mongoid::Document
  field       :name,        :type => String
  field       :description, :type => String
  field       :public,      :type => Boolean, :default => false
  has_many    :posts, :class_name => 'FeedPost'
  embedded_in :user

  def isSubscribed? user
    res = user.feedsubscribtions.where :userId => self.user.id, :feedId => self.id
    res.count > 0
  end
end

class Feedsubscribtion
  include Mongoid::Document
  field       :userId, :type => String
  field       :feedId, :type => String
  embedded_in :user

  def Owner
    user = User.where :id => self.userId
    if user != nil then user.first else nil end
  end

  def Feed
    user = Owner()
    feed = user.feeds.where :id => self.feedId
    if feed != nil then feed.first else nil end
  end
end
```

Everything with the Feed model and controllers work just swell. I just have this problem with FeedControllers and a few other classes, that doesn't have associated controllers, and just don't seem to even exist in my Rails project as far as the controllers are concerned.

And then I have my feedsubscribtion_controller :

```
class FeedsubscribtionsController < ApplicationController
  has_to_be_connected

  def create
    if session[:user_id] != params[:id]
      @self        = CurrentUser()
      subscribtion = Feedsubscribtion.new :userId => params[:id], :feedId => params[:feed]
      @self.feedsubscribtions |=  [ subscribtion ]
      render json: { success: @self.save(validate: false), feed: params[:feed] }
    end
  end

  def destroy
    if session[:user_id] != params[:id]
      @self    = CurrentUser()
      uid, fid = BSON::ObjectId.new(params[:id]), BSON::ObjectId.new(params[:feed])
      @feed    = @self.feedsubscribtions.where :userId => uid, :fid => fid
      if @feed.count > 0
        @feed.first.delete
    @self.save(validate: false)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I've been trying to make a workaround, where a method of Feed would return me the instance of Feedsubscribtion. It worked for "create" : not for "destroy". Because it seems Mongoid::Document.where tries to use FeedSubscribtion. And fails, of course.

What's happening to me ?
Why the hell Rails doesn't make Feedsubscribtion available outside of its own file ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, rename your model to **FeedSubscription**, then place it in a file at **app/models/feed_subscription.rb**. Then change the references at your controllers to access the **FeedSubscription** class and rename your methods **Owner** and **Feed** and **CurrentUser**, as methods should **always be defined in lowercase in Ruby**.

When you define something starting with an uppercase in Ruby it makes it a constant.

Comment: And do the same with the controller `feed_subscriptions_controller.rb`